# 2016 ssrs secondary axis auto range not working

Tags: reporting-services

I have an 2016 SSRS report with 3 Values and 1 Category Group

The first 2 values are hours per month and the 3rd Value is Agency spend
I've added a secondary axis for $value of agency spend
Secondary Vertical Axis Properties is set for Min: Auto and Max: Auto
This returns the Secondary Vertical Axis of $0 to $100 as the range when in fact the Agency $values are around $0 to $4000
When I set the Max to $5000, it works.
I've created this in Visual Studio 2017 with SSDT 2017.  Wondering if this is a bug with the SSDT 2017?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I assume that the first two series are set on the primary axis?

Comment: Yes the 2 first 2 values are in a stacked % chart on the primary axis so I get a CAS Hours % of all hours. The 3rd value of Agency is a line chart on the Secondary axis.